# label X axis on ggscatter

Tags: r, graphics, axis-labels

I have a dataframe with 2 columns to do a correlation. The data is of integer number from 1 to 10.
However, when I use the ggscatter, the axis (X and Y) uses a scale of 0, 2.5, 5, 7.5 and 10. I want to change it. It doesn't need to be all the number, however it never will be 2.5 or 7.5.

How can I make this?

Here are my code (with a sample to make this example).

```
X_AXIS = sample(c(1:10),size = 100, replace = TRUE)
Y_AXIS = sample(c(1:10),size = 100, replace = TRUE)

novaTabela = data.frame(X_AXIS, Y_AXIS)
ggscatter(novaTabela, x = "X_AXIS", y = "Y_AXIS", 
          add = "reg.line", 
          cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just by adding the labels and breaks to the scale using `scale_x_continuous` (or `scale_y_continuous`) as we do in ggplot. Also, note that, whatever change you make to the `label`, define those for `breaks` argument too.

```r
library(ggpubr)

X_AXIS = sample(c(1:10),size = 100, replace = TRUE)
Y_AXIS = sample(c(1:10),size = 100, replace = TRUE)

novaTabela = data.frame(X_AXIS, Y_AXIS)

p <- ggscatter(novaTabela, x = "X_AXIS", y = "Y_AXIS", 
          add = "reg.line", 
          cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson")

p + scale_x_continuous(labels = seq(1, 10, 3), breaks = seq(1, 10, 3))
```

[image: ggpubr plot with manually defined scale label]